# Grails MongoDB full text search

Tags: mongodb, grails, full-text-search

i've tried to use mongoDB full text feature that is described there :
http://grails.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongodb/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20MongoDB%20Collections.html

nevertheless, it does not seem to work...

i have this in my domain class

```
static mapping = {
    collection "Record"
//index record_name:"text"
index record_name:"text", record_synonyms:"text", record_shortname:"text"

}
```

this is the search i've done in my controller:

```
def search = {
    def result = Record.search("protein")
    log.debug("result : "+ result)

    def resultTop = Product.searchTop("protein")
    log.debug("resultTop : "+ resultTop)

    respond Record.list()
}
```

the response i obtained when is run search in my browser is :

```
 URI : /Gral_mongodb_grails/record/search
 Class : com.mongodb.MongoException
 Message : invalid operator: $search
```

anyone has an idea of what is wrong?

Comment: I wonder if there is some sort of bug with creating the text index that spans multiple fields. Can you try opening up a mongo shell and run `db.Record.getIndexes()` to see if the text index is getting created properly? I would suspect it's not.

Comment: it seems it has been created :
    {
    (...)
                "ns" : "ChloroKB.Record",
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "ns" : "ChloroKB.Record",
                "name" :      "record_name_text_record_synonyms_text_record_shortname
_text"

Comment: what version of MongoDB are you using? Text search is disable by default on versions prior to 2.6. Could be the problem. Your code looks correct to me.

Comment: i am using mongo 2.6.5 and have upgrade the plugin version to 3.0.2. 
I still got the same error :/

Comment: I was wrong. I thought i was using mongodb 2.6 but actually in my path i still had 2.4.8.
I fixed it, and now it works. Thanks a lot allTwentyQuestions, you give the way to fix it!